# drop down not showing in Xcode 4 while code signing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I made a project in Xcode 4.2, but not able to select the required certificate in code sign identity column. Xcode is not even showing any drop down in that column after adding certificates in organizer to, only text box appears.

Answer (score 24):

I have previously struggled with this problem myself until I found out that all you have to do is toggle "Show Values" in the Editor menu. This brought back the drop down menu for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I nearly want to delete and reinstall my Xcode to solve the problem. I don't think I manually toggled the Show Values and Show Definitions menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your bundle identifier matches that of app identifier which you used to create your provisioning profile. You can edit the bundle identifier in `info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

i see the same problem ever since I began coding. What I found out is that if I write myself the names of the certificates I have installed, it works just as well. I have been able to submit adhoc distributions and also to the store. it must be the same name exactly.